# Intersect extension method, case sensitivity not working

Tags: vb.net, extension-methods

I am trying to compare the contents of 2 collections in a unit test in .NET using MSTEST. To make things simple, instead of having to .Sort() and then loop through the collection and compare items one at a time, I've found the new and very cool .Intersect Extension method.

It seems to work great by doing:

```
         Assert.AreEqual(expected.Count, actual.Intersect(expected).Count)
```

However, now that I have a test which needs to be case-sensitive, it breaks. I've tried sending Intersect's second parameter StringComparer.Ordinal,StringComparer.InvariantCulture, and StringComparer.CurrentCulture... no luck..

Anyone experience this before?

thanks!

EDIT: here is the data:

```
 Actual:
    (0) "FOO"   String
    (1) "foo"   String
    (2) "Foo"   String
    (3) "fOo"   String
    (4) "foO"   String
    (5) "BAR"   String
    (6) "BAR"   String
    (7) "BAZ"   String
    (8) "baz"   String
    (9) "foo"   String

 Expected:

    (0) "FOO"   String
    (1) "foo"   String
    (2) "Foo"   String
    (3) "fOo"   String
    (4) "foO"   String
    (5) "BAR"   String
    (6) "BAR"   String
    (7) "BAZ"   String
    (8) "baz"   String
    (9) "foo"   String

 actual.Intersect(expected, StringComparer.CurrentCulture)

    (0) "FOO"   String
    (1) "foo"   String
    (2) "Foo"   String
    (3) "fOo"   String
    (4) "foO"   String
    (5) "BAR"   String
    (6) "BAZ"   String
    (7) "baz"   String
```

It seems to be removing a matching duplicate 'foo', and a matching duplicate 'BAZ'. Perhaps there is a better way to assert collections are matching?

**_EDIT2: I think Intersect() removes duplicates, which is why this is breaking. I Found the CollectionAssert Class.  This is exactly what I needed! Thanks! _**

Comment: When you say "it breaks" and "no luck", what do you mean?  Do you mean "it breaks" as in "it gives the wrong count"?  Do you mean "no luck" as in "it gives the same wrong result"?

Comment: Also, are you certain that the case-insensitive one works correctly, and doesn't just coincidentally give the correct count?

Comment: And also, you might want to take a look at the CollectionAssert class, which may be more appropriate for what you're trying to do.

Comment: The count is not correct, it seems to be removing 2 matches that it shouldn't. I pasted the data above. Thanks for pointing out the CollectionAssert class. This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For testing purposes use `CollectionAssert.AreEqual(actual, expected)`

You were looking for [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx), not [Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx). Intersect returns the intersection of two sequences, ie. the items shared between them. Using Intersect on { 1, 2, 3 } and { 3, 4, 5 } would return 3. SequenceEqual would return false.

Had you not found CollectionAssert you could've used:

```
Assert.IsTrue(actual.SequenceEqual(expected))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did look at the MSDN doc you posted.. one thing to note, SequenceEqual seems to compare references... not actual values... so I think SequenceEqual still would have failed without implementing IComparable. Still good to know though! thanks again

Comment: @dferraro np... for a collection of strings or ints etc. you can use it directly and the default equality comparer is used for the values of the given type. For a custom class it would need an `IEqualityComparer` to determine just how to compare the objects.

Answer (score 1):

Implement an IEqualityComparer like so:

`Class StringCaseInsensitiveComparer

    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of String)

    
Public Function Equals(ByVal s1 As String, ByVal s2 As String) As Boolean

        Return s1.ToLower() = s2.ToLower()

    End Function

    
Public Function GetHashCode(ByVal s As String) As Integer

        Return s.GetHashCode()

    End Function

End Class`

Then, call this overload of Intersect:

`Dim first As IEnumerable(Of TSource)

Dim second As IEnumerable(Of TSource)

Dim comparer As IEqualityComparer(Of TSource)

Dim returnValue As IEnumerable(Of TSource)`

passing it an instance of the comparer that you just made.

Comment: Thanks - I figured out I should be using CollectionAssert. But going back to the original problem - shouldn't the InvariantCulture and CurrentCulture comparers do exactly what you are doing here? They say in their documentation 'does a case sensitive compare'..

Comment: Sorry, instead try using StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase, or StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.

Comment: I realized that the issue isn't about case sensitivity - if you look at the above data, it seems that intersect() is filtering out duplicates. This is the issue

Comment: @dferraro: intersect does filter them out, in a sense. I explained a bit in my response.